# Convert SQL Server queries to SQLite queries

Tags: conversion, sql-server, sqlite

What is the best converter to convert the SQL query to sqlite query? I have a script file  which have lot of scripts written in SQLServer. I want to convert it to SQLite queries. Please suggest me a good converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can achieve my requirement by the visual studio project available in the following link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB

This will convert the existing sql server db to sqlite db.

http://sqlitestudio.pl/
https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitemanstudio/?source=typ_redirect

The above links are for management studios of sqlite. We can get queries from those management studios by generating scripts.